# OpenSSL Symfony2 version

Tags: symfony, openssl

How do i change the openssl version or path with Symfony2
When running `phpinfo()` it shows `OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015` but when i run in terminal with `openssl version -a` it shows `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016` and thats the one i want to use.

How can i change the path to openssl for Symfony2. The path where `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016` is located is `/usr/local/bin/openssl` and it seems like Symfony2 openssl is located at Xcode openssl because it is showing `-with-openssl=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/local`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Symfony OpenSSL problem but a PHP problem.

You should recompile your PHP with --with-openssl=/usr/local/bin/openssl